# FreeRADIUS can not login with Active Directory user

Tags: active-directory, debian, samba, freeradius, winbind

I install freeradius 3 in debian 9. I can login with user from text file in radius but I want to login with user from Active Directory.

First, I install this library.

**apt install samba winbind krb5-user krb5-config -y**

Then I config realm like this.

```
Default Kerberos version 5 realm: XXX.EDU
Kerberos servers for your realm: ad.xxx.local
Administrative server for your Kerberos realm: ad.xxx.local
```

In file /etc/samba/smb.conf . I put this code under line workgroup = XXX

```
security = ADS
realm = XXX.EDU
encrypt passwords = yes
client use spnego = yes

idmap config *:backend = tdb
idmap config *:range = 2000-9999
idmap config XXX:backend = ad
idmap config XXX:schema_mode = rfc2307
idmap config XXX:range = 10000-99999

winbind nss info = rfc2307
winbind trusted domains only = no
winbind use default domain = yes
winbind enum users  = yes
winbind enum groups = yes
winbind refresh tickets = Yes
```

In file /etc/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = XXX.EDU
dns_lookup_realm = true
dns_lookup_kdc = false
forwardable = true

[realms]
XXX.EDU = {
 kdc = ad.xxx.local
 admin_server = ad.xxx.local
}

[domain_realm]
.xxx.local = XXX.EDU
xxx.local = XXX.EDU
```

After reboot server I use this command.

```
net ads join -U Administrator
```

It's join success.

```
Joined 'XXX' to dns domain 'xxx.edu'
```

After that, I use this command for check user but it not show anything.

```
wbinfo -u
```

I test user login with this command.

```
usr/bin/ntlm_auth --domain=XXX --username=user_ad@xxx.edu --password=pass_user_ad
```

It's show error like this. I'm sure I have user user_ad@xxx.edu in AD but It's not found user.

```
NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER: No such user (0xc0000064)
```

If I change domain like this.

```
usr/bin/ntlm_auth --domain=XXX.EDU --username=user_ad@xxx.edu --password=pass_user_ad
```

It's show error.

```
NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY: Memory allocation error (0xc0000017)
```

How to use active directory user with freeradius ?

Answer (score 0):

add active directory ip as nameserver and domain ad search domainname in /etc/resolve.conf file.